# Adding new records and displaying them on visualforce page from custom object

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex, custom-object

I get an error in visualforce page now. Saying:

> Error:Unknown property 'tudent__cStandardController.d'

This happens when I add the delete commandLink button to the vf page. Before I add it it doesn't put out an error but on it doesn't display records on the page.

Thanks for help in advance

Visualforce code:

```
    <apex:page standardController="tudent__c" extensions="vidsav">
    <apex:form >
       <apex:outputPanel id="check">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Dodaj Študenta">
          <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Name }"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.priimek__c }"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Datum_rojstva__c }"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.letnik__c }"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Naslov__c }"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.naziv_fakultete__c }"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.tudijski_program__c }"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.tip_tudija__c }">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="check" />
            </apex:inputField>
            <apex:inputField value="{! tudent__c.Samopla_nik__c }" rendered="{!IF( tudent__c.tip_tudija__c == 'izredni', true, false )}" />
          </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock>
       </apex:outputPanel>    
    <apex:pageBlock title="Študenti">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!studentsR}" var="s" >
       <apex:commandLink action="{!deleteStudent}" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;">`enter code here`Del
    <apex:param value="{!d.Id}" name="idToDel" assignTo="{!SelectedStudentId}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
         <apex:column value="{!s.Name}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!s.priimek__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!s.Datum_rojstva__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!s.letnik__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!s.Naslov__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!s.naziv_fakultete__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!s.tudijski_program__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!s.tip_tudija__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!s.Samopla_nik__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class vidsav {

public vidsav(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

}

public List<tudent__c> studentsR {get;set;}
public String SelectedStudentId {get;set;}

public vidsav() {
    loadData();

}         

public void loadData() {

    studentsR = [Select id,Name,priimek__c,Datum_rojstva__c,letnik__c,Naslov__c,naziv_fakultete__c,tudijski_program__c,tip_tudija__c,Samopla_nik__c, CreatedDate from tudent__c Order By CreatedDate desc];

}

public void deleteStudent(){

   studentsR = [Select id,Name,priimek__c,Datum_rojstva__c,letnik__c,Naslov__c,naziv_fakultete__c,tudijski_program__c,tip_tudija__c,Samopla_nik__c, CreatedDate from tudent__c where id = :SelectedStudentId];

  if(studentsR.size() > 0 || studentsR[0].Id != ''){

  delete studentsR;

  }

 loadData();

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated code you should use ->

1) Update your PageBlockTable to this -

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!studentsR}" var="s" >
     <apex:column value="{!s.Name}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!s.priimek__c}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!s.Datum_rojstva__c}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!s.letnik__c}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!s.Naslov__c}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!s.naziv_fakultete__c}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!s.tudijski_program__c}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!s.tip_tudija__c}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!s.Samopla_nik__c}"/>
     <apex:column>
         <apex:commandLink action="{!deleteStudent}" onclick="if(!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;" value="Del">
             <apex:param value="{!s.Id}" name="idToDel" assignTo="{!SelectedStudentId}"/>
         </apex:commandLink>
     </apex:column>
```

You needed to put your `commandLink` inside an apex:column in order for it to display correctly in the `pageBlockTable` and also of course the `d` had to be replaced with a `s` since your table variable is `s` (var="s").

2) Update your Controller to this -

```
public class vidsav {

public vidsav(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    loadData();
}

public List<Account> studentsR {get;set;}
public String SelectedStudentId {get;set;}      

public void loadData() {

    studentsR = [Select id,Name,priimek__c,Datum_rojstva__c,letnik__c,Naslov__c,naziv_fakultete__c,tudijski_program__c,tip_tudija__c,Samopla_nik__c, CreatedDate from tudent__c Order By CreatedDate desc];

}

public void deleteStudent(){

   studentsR = [Select id,Name,priimek__c,Datum_rojstva__c,letnik__c,Naslov__c,naziv_fakultete__c,tudijski_program__c,tip_tudija__c,Samopla_nik__c, CreatedDate from tudent__c where id = :SelectedStudentId];

    if(studentsR.size() > 0 || studentsR[0].Id != ''){

      delete studentsR;

    }
    loadData();

  }

}
```

You were using two constructors and were calling loadData() from the wrong one and this is why it was not loading data. With this you will be able to delete records and reload your table.

Comment: I get an error in apex class: "Error: Compile Error: The method object <Constructor>(ApexPages.StandardController) is referenced by Visualforce Page.Remove the usage and try again." and it is pointing at this line: "public String SelectedStudentId {get;set;}". Any idead? tried googling it and not really managed to fix it.

Comment: can you post your updated code with the controller? Can't really help without looking at the code.

Comment: Updated the the code and the post. Got new error, see above in post.

Comment: change `<apex:param value="{!d.Id}" name="idToDel" assignTo="{!SelectedStudentId}"/>` to `<apex:param value="{!s.Id}" name="idToDel" assignTo="{!SelectedStudentId}"/>` because your pageBlock variable is represented by "s" and not "d". I also updated my answer, have a look, your delete should work fine now.

Comment: And in case you want to Save the current account and not reload the page, you should change your button action to quickSave instead of Save - 
`<apex:commandButton action="{!quickSave}" value="Save" />`

Comment: Yes I figured the mistakes with constructor and vf page delete buttons myself. Nevertheless thank you for your help man. I learned a lot ^^

Comment: Glad to help ^^. If you found this answer to be correct then you can mark it so it can help and benefit the community

Comment: sorry for late response. Yes of course I marked it. Have a good one :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace {!d.Id} with {!s.Id}
The variable used to traverse the records in the pageblocktable is s not d.